# Problems with Search on graph

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

When i search for something in my computer like:
https://graph.facebook.com/search?q=swarmetrics&type=post&limit=75
return 6 results, but, when I search the same in another computer or another browser, returns nothing

what I'm missing?

Comment: **RESOLVED!!!**   ---   The problem was that Graph uses the **locale** from the browser when none is specified, and I try it in browsers with a different locale setting (ES_LA and EN_US). That's why I got diferent results. Thanks to all!

Answer (score 1):

I get an empty result as well, and also if I try to search in the facebook search box and then select "Public Posts" I get "No results found for your query".

Maybe the user you are logged in with has access to some private results for that query.
Try loggin into facebook from the other browser/computer with the same user and then make the search.

Comment: The result is the same in both cases when I'm loggin in or not. The user from where I get the results is this http://www.facebook.com/people/Metrics-Swarm-B/100003776045990 is a public profile. What else can it be?

Comment: Really? Can you please try to curl it, that is *curl "ttps://graph.facebook.com/search?q=swarmetrics&type=post&limit=75"*, I got back: *{"data":[]}*, you get something else?

Answer (score 0):

Been experiencing similar results lately where our dev machines and local machines will return empty results for a known good search, while the production server and other off-site machines will return results. It typically lasts for 30min-2hrs then things work normally again. I've filed a fb bug ticket here http://developers.facebook.com/bugs/456910301017301?browse=search_509b0c1b72a008e55394686